# Loading pivoted data from csv to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading data from CSV to snowflake which is already pivoted as shown in attached file. This is a monthly data that I have to load with automation.

How to do create a table in snowflake to take care of pivoted data for the past and future load. I just want to extract the data as is and want to make sure every month the date column is not affected.

[image]

Comment: What's the largest this file could get?

Comment: file size is not an issue, new monthly file will have only two columns(account and month). number of rows are under 10K. So new file will get appended.

Comment: Ok, so there's one file with a lot of columns (the one pictured) and 10k rows. Then the future files will only have 2 columns, and 10k rows. How should data look once loadded?

Comment: Correct. Data should look the way it is looking in the screenshot. New month column will get added at the end.

Comment: Designing a table like this, where you have to add new columns in order to load new data, is a really bad idea. Best practice would be to load the raw data  into Snowflake and then you can pivot it as needed. If you really need to load pre-pivoted data then you’d probably need to drop and re-create the table each time you load data into it